# Should I create NSError or use the new error handling mechanism in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, exception

As the title says, should I create my own `NSError` instances when things go wrong in my code or should I create subtypes of `ErrorType`and use the error handling that is in Swift 2?

And what should I do in methods that get an NSError from the framework (file API etc) and I also have some additional logic that needs to make an error, should I convert the NSError to ErrorType in some way and then use ErrorType all the way, or should I mix them...?

I don't understand how this works or should look like.

Answer (score 0):

NSError supports the protocol ErrorType. You cannot "convert" NSError to ErrorType, because ErrorType is a protocol, not a struct or class. You can cast to ErrorType, so the compiler forgets it is an NSError, but it still remains an NSError.

Answer (score 0):

As @gnasher729 said, `NSError` conforms to the `ErrorType` protocol, so all NSError instances **are** of type ErrorType. No conversion is necessary. NSError is pretty flexible, so you might want to stick with it. You can define your own error domain for NSError with its own error codes for your app-specific errors. If there's an underlying framework error you want to keep, you can put it in NSError's user dictionary, using the `NSUnderlyingErrorKey` as the key and the NSError instance as the value.

Check out [the documentation for NSError](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806) and see if it meets your needs. If it doesn't, you can define your own struct that conforms to ErrorType that works how you want it.